# Entity form gets null value in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to add to **Model entity** one choice from **Marka entity**. 
I've problem with data from choices form. Form has got all data inside, but when I send the form i get error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO model (nazwa, idm) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["a", null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idm' cannot be null
```

When i check source code I see that value is correctly:

```
   <select id="namefield_idm" name="namefield[idm]" class="form-control"> 
           <option value="1" >Opel</option>
           <option value="2" >Mazda</option> 
           <option value="3" >Ford</option>
    </select>
```

I don't have any idea whats wrong. My ModelType.php

```
  <?php
namespace UTPBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


    class ModelType extends AbstractType

{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('nazwa', 'text', array('label' => 'Nazwa',  'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control')
        ))
        ->add('idm', 'entity', array(
            'label'    => 'Marka',
            'mapped'   => false,
            'class'    => 'UTPBundle:Marka',
            'choice_label' => 'nazwa',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ),
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
            },
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Dodaj',  'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-success'
        )));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{

}

 public function getName()
    {
        return 'namefield';
    }
}
?>
```

My code from controller looks like:

```
/**
     * @Route("/model", name="utp_model")
     */
    public function modelAction(Request $request)
    {

        $name = 'Model';


        $model = new Model();
        $marka = new Marka();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ModelType($marka), $model);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($model);
                $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('UTPBundle:Default:model.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

And model entity also:

```
<?php

namespace UTPBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Model
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Model
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nazwa", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nazwa;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idm", type="integer")
     */
    private $idm;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set idm
     *
     * @param integer $idm
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    public function setIdm($idm)
    {
        $this->idm = $idm;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idm
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdm()
    {
        return $this->idm;
    }

    /**
     * Set nazwa
     *
     * @param string $nazwa
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    public function setNazwa($nazwa)
    {
        $this->nazwa = $nazwa;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nazwa
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNazwa()
    {
        return $this->nazwa;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully clear from your question but I understand that what you want to do is to have a `Model` entity which will include a `Marka` field. If that is the case, then first of all, you do not want to store your Marka as an integer within your Model, you want to store it as a Marka object with a (probably) ManyToOne relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Marka")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idm", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $marka;
```

Doctrine will take care of using an integer to represent this relationship as an integer within your database, using the `idm` column

Once you have done this, you can then use it in your ModelType form without using `'mapped' => false`:

```
    ->add('marka', 'entity', array(
        'label'    => 'Marka',
        'class'    => 'UTPBundle:Marka',
        'choice_label' => 'nazwa',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ),
    ))
```

(Notice that you do not need the `query_builder` option since your query builder just returns all the objects and the entity field by default already does that.)

And last you just need to modify your controller a bit since you will not need now to create any `Marka` object:

```
    $model = new Model();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ModelType(), $model);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's fine :))))))

Answer (score 0):

In

```
->add('idm', 'entity', array(
            'label'    => 'Marka',
            'mapped'   => false,
            'class'    => 'UTPBundle:Marka',
            'choice_label' => 'nazwa',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ),
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
            },
        ))
```

Remove the line

```
'mapped'   => false
```

Mapped false means don't map that property to the underlying object, so it won't be persisted and will then cause your database error.

Comment: Unfortunally, no ;/ i removed this line and now error is: `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO model (nazwa, idm) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["aaa", {}]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class UTPBundle\Entity\Marka could not be converted to string`

Comment: You might want to look into a data transformer for that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html - because you don't have a proper entity relationship between marka and model. Ideally you would, in which case the answer below (Carlos) is what you should follow.